# Jenkins - Copying Jenkins made Build artifacts to other location or Fileserver

Tags: jenkins, build-automation, copy-paste, jenkins-plugins

We recently started using Jenkins for making our Builds. Being a CM person, I am able to compile the Code and gettings Build artifacts at Jenkins machine itself. From Jenkins machine, we are using bactch scripts to copy the Build artifacts to our Fileserver. Here my Query, in Jenkins is there any plugin that automatically copied Build artifacts from Jenkins workplace location to our Fileservers or to any remote location. I need a plugin to do all this Job. This helps me use bactch scripts that were written by me and sometimes it is getting failed by using batch files AND this seems my Build artifacts are copying authentically. 
Please help me to find a plugin which automatically copies Build artifacts to remote machine or Fileserver. Thanks all for your help.

Regards,
Suresh Kumar.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the list of [Artifact uploader](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Plugins#Plugins-Artifactuploaders) plugins. BTW, very often, you don't need more than an additional build step and the `copy` command to copy a file to a file server.

Comment: Sorry to ask out of date, but I am new on Jenkins. Could you be more specific about `copy` command you mentioned above.

Comment: The copy command that is provided by the Operating system. So under windows you create a "Execute Windows Batch command" and put `copy file.txt file2.txt` in it to create a copy of file.txt.

Comment: @PeterSchuetze I have jenkins installed on Linux and want to copy folder to remote windoz server ! How to do that ?

Comment: @AshishKarpe There are different options. One option is to mount the windows folder using cifs (or other protocols/tools) on the linux machine and copy the file using cp. Another option is to use ftp/sftp to transmit the file to the windows server. Regardless on what option you choose some setup need to be done on the systems outside of Jenkins. A different approach is to put a jenkins slave on the target server and have another job use the artifacts of the first job. Job 2 can then do a local copy of the file. Jenkins will take care of copying the files between the two jobs.